# How to translate variable string in js file?

Tags: magento2, translate, i18n

Let's say I have the following code:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate',
], function (
    $,
    $t
) {
    'use strict';
    return function (str) {
        //Rest of codes to determine output
        return $t(return_string);
    });
}
```

I have all possible values of `return_string` on translate file. But it fails to translate at all on frontend. What can I do here to make `return_string` return translated string?

Comment: Are you using this return_string somewhere? I mean in phtml or html?

Comment: I use it on html

Comment: Did you try translating it in html?

Comment: I tried with no avail. Anyway, I solved it by inject the translated string in the file. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue before. The problem is, that the "keys" that you want to translate need to be rendered in a phtml or HTML file first.

I usually do this in a hidden .

Comment: Anyway, I solved it by inject the translated string in the file. Thanks for your help!